# How to Fix Synaptic Error 403 problem?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, synaptic

I'm having an annoying issue with Synaptic Package Manager on Linux Mint where it's just giving me Error 403 when I try to update the repository list. I can't figure out the source of the problem, because all the sources are current and up-to-date. I've even tried removing all the sources and adding one at a time, but I'm still getting the errors.

```
Failed to fetch http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists/precise/steam/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists/precise/steam/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists/precise/steam/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_14.04/./Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirrors.hustunique.com/linuxmint/dists/rebecca/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirrors.hustunique.com/linuxmint/dists/rebecca/upstream/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirrors.hustunique.com/linuxmint/dists/rebecca/import/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirrors.hustunique.com/linuxmint/dists/rebecca/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirrors.hustunique.com/linuxmint/dists/rebecca/upstream/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirrors.hustunique.com/linuxmint/dists/rebecca/import/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirrors.hustunique.com/linuxmint/dists/rebecca/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirrors.hustunique.com/linuxmint/dists/rebecca/upstream/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirrors.hustunique.com/linuxmint/dists/rebecca/import/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty/universe/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty/multiverse/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://extra.linuxmint.com/dists/rebecca/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://extra.linuxmint.com/dists/rebecca/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://extra.linuxmint.com/dists/rebecca/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty-updates/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty-updates/universe/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bartbes/love-stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bartbes/love-stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bartbes/love-stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cinelerra-ppa/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cinelerra-ppa/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cinelerra-ppa/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dimula73/krita/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dimula73/krita/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dimula73/krita/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/frederik-elwert/transcribe/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/frederik-elwert/transcribe/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/frederik-elwert/transcribe/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/glennric/dolphin-emu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/glennric/dolphin-emu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/glennric/dolphin-emu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mamarley/nvidia/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mamarley/nvidia/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mamarley/nvidia/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/deepin-sc/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/deepin-sc/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/deepin-sc/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ppsspp/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ppsspp/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ppsspp/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried changing different servers to download the packages but the error is still there, and it's getting really annoying… What do I need to do to **force** it to update properly?

Comment: Does the command `sudo apt-get update` works?

Comment: Also, if it won't work — just to be sure, install the package `httping`, and try a command `httping http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages`. Tell, if that worked, or no. If you can't install the httping because of non-updated packages, you may [download it from here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=httping&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all)

Comment: @Hi-Angel - `apt-get` is the same as being done through Synaptic. `httping`  returns that I can connect to it just fine, but I'm still not able to update to retrieve new packages.